# Bootloader will not decrease register value in loop

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader

I am creating a bootloader in assembly language; having it create a Christmas tree using a loop and using linux bash to run it, but i am facing a problem when trying to subtract from the register so the loop would terminate.
I tried creating a function in order to decrease the value of the register but the function Trunk only runs once

```
[BITS 16] 
[ORG 0x7C00] 
top: 
    ;; Put 0 into ds (data segment) 
    ;; Can't do it directly 
    mov ax,0x0000 
    mov ds,ax 
    ;; si is the location relative to the data segment of the 
    ;; string/char to display  
    mov ch, 5 ;
    mov cl, 1 ;
    call Pyramid
    mov ch, 4 ;
    mov cl, 3
    mov al, 2
    call Trunk
    jmp $ ; Spin 
    
Pyramid:
    mov dh, ch ; print the dot 
    mov dl, cl; dec ch
    call SPACE;
    call DO;
    dec ch;
    add cl, 2;
    mov si, cr 
    call writeString ; See below 
    cmp ch, 0 ; compare to see if what is store in ch is 0
    jne Pyramid ; if ch does not contain 0 call dotsLoop again.
    ret ;
    
Trunk: 
    mov dh, ch;
    mov dl, cl;
    call SPACE
    call DO
    call TLevel
    mov si, cr
    call writeString
    cmp al, 0
    jmp Trunk
    ret ;
    
TLevel:
    dec al
    ret 
SPACE:
    mov si, S;
    call writeString;
    dec dh;
    cmp dh, 0;
    jne SPACE;
    ret;
DO:
    mov si, D;
    call writeString;
    dec dl;
    cmp dl, 0;
    jne DO;
    ret;
writeString: 
    mov ah,0x0E ; Display a chacter (as before) 
    mov bh,0x00 ;
    mov bl,0x07; 
nextchar: 
    Lodsb ; Loads [SI] into AL and increases SI by one 
    ;; Effectively "pumps" the string through AL 
    cmp al,0 ; End of the string? 
    jz done 
    int 0x10 ; BIOS interrupt 
    jmp nextchar 
done: 
    ret 
    S db ' ',0 ; Null-terminated 
    D db '*',0 ;
    cr db 13,10,0;
    times 510-($-$$) db 0;
    dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: This is a bootloader.  You can't run it as a native Linux executable.  It would crash when it reached an `int 0x10`, if you built it into an ELF executable.  I assume that's not what you're actually doing and you just described it wrong.  Hopefully you're running it in something with a debugger that lets you single step.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried creating a function in order to decrease the value of the register but the function Trunk only runs once

In your *TLevel* routine you use the `AL` register for counting the iterations of *Trunk*, but you forget that all of those calls to *SPACE*, *DO*, and *writeString* clobber the value in `AL`.

Either select a different register as a counter or preserve the `AX` register in the *writeString* procedure.

```
writeString:
    PUSH AX       ; PRESERVE AX
    mov  ah, 0x0E 
    mov  bx, 0x0007 
nextchar: 
    Lodsb 
    cmp  al, 0
    je   done 
    int  0x10
    jmp  nextchar 
done:
    POP  AX       ; RESTORE AX
    ret
```

---

> ```
> Trunk:
>   ...
>   cmp al, 0
>   jmp Trunk
>   ret
> ```

In order to actually loop depending on the counter in `AL`, you need to replace that unconditional jump `jmp` by the conditional jump `jne`.

Do note that having a separate routine just to `dec al` is wasteful.
Why don't you write *Trunk* this way:

```
Trunk: 
    mov  dx, cx   ; LOAD BOTH COUNTERS IN ONE INSTRUCTION
    call SPACE
    call DO
    mov  si, cr
    call writeString
    dec  al
    jnz  Trunk
    ret
```